# Array of Objects Compare and Exclude

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I am using this handy function:

```
function not(a, b) {
  return a.filter((value) => b.indexOf(value) === -1);
}
```

Then I have this

```
let AvailableList = not(FullList, MyList);
```

If I were to give example of first element in MyList and FullList it is:

```
appName: "MyAppName*"
description: null
permissionID: MyAppID*
permissionName: "MyAppPermName*"
__proto__: Object
```

So initially AvailableList is full of items like above. When user makes selection and saves it I save it into MyList. So then I need to use this not function to calculate remaining parts from MyList. But even when I move the first item of AvailableList to MyList then check like `if(AvailableList === MyList) console.log(true) else console.log(false)` I get false. But if I console log both of the array's first items they print identical values. I tried to compare after declaring variables using `Object.assign()` as well but no help.

Perhaps I can tackle this easily checking a value like permissionID, but I do not want to go that route since there will be other items later on that won't have permissionID.

If you know of a different function that can do a better job, feel free to share. Please don't share library solutions like Lodash.

- *entries are masked

Comment: what property do you want to compare?

Comment: Comparing objects with `===` compares them as instances. Two separate object instances are never `===` to each other. It's not very clear however from your question whether that could be the problem, because you didn't post the code that builds the arrays involved.

Comment: I want to compare whole object. so array I have is full of objects like this and I want to compare whole object at a time so I can give (array1,array2) then it would give me back a result of array that has all elements of array1 but removed all elements of array2

Comment: @Pointy it doesnt compare by ===. It uses indexOf then checks the value of that to see if it's -1. AvailableList has all items full of objects like in the example I provided. MyList is empty initially then user selects and moves items on the page which then some of the array items gets moved to MyList

Comment: But `.indexOf()` compares internally with `===`.

Comment: Try it in the browser console: `console.log([{}].indexOf({}))` will be -1

Comment: hmm well then in another file I have this and it works fine.. `const [left, setLeft] = React.useState(props.AvailableList); const [right, setRight] = React.useState(props.MyList);` when user clicks I kick in `setLeft(not(left, leftChecked));` this portion in another class works entirely fine.

Comment: As I said in the first comment, it's not 100% clear whether that is the problem because you posted nothing from the code that *builds* the arrays.

Comment: AvailableList gets build by Permission system that has bunch of objects like in the example. It's all like this `[{appName: "MyAppName*" description: null permissionID: MyAppID* permissionName: "MyAppPermName*"},{appName: "MyAppName*" description: null permissionID: MyAppID* permissionName: "MyAppPermName*"}]` etc.. My List is initially empty then when user moves any item that is in AvailableList then MyList gets it's items.